# CSS_SELECTOR not working Python w/ Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

[image]I am trying to access the second link with the class = "TabLink_tab__uKOPj"

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

def go_to_url(driver, url):
    driver.get(url)
    #cookies accept 
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
    time.sleep(1)
    pass 




def main(): 
    driver = webdriver.Firefox() 
    driver.maximize_window() 
    url = r"https://www.nba.com/games"
    go_to_url(driver, url) 

    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"class#TabLink_tab__uKOPj"))).select_by_index(1)
 
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    main()
```

this is what my code looks like, attached is the webpage. if you can help it would be much appreciated.

p.s. how can I learn about css selector like this better

Comment: try `(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".TabLink_tab__uKOPj")`

Comment: Screenshots of the UI are great, screenshots of code or HTML are not. Please read why [a screenshot of code/HTML is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the HTML as text and properly format it instead. Grab the entire SECTION tag around that element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CSS selector below.

```
(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[data-text='BOX SCORE']")
```

I prefer it because it's more human readable. If it stops working in the future, it's pretty clear what that locator was looking for... something related to box scores where the class you are using just looks like random text making it harder to correlate to something on the page.

Your code would then look like

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[data-text='BOX SCORE']")))
```

---

NOTE: There are a couple issues with your CSS selector:

```
(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "class#TabLink_tab__uKOPj")
```

1. You used 'class' instead of 'a', the tag name
2. You used `#` (indicating an ID) instead of `.` indicating a class.

It should have been

```
(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.TabLink_tab__uKOPj")
```

---

Here are a few references that will help you learn CSS selectors.

1. [W3C CSS selectors spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#overview)
2. [Selenium Tips: CSS Selectors](https://saucelabs.com/resources/blog/selenium-tips-css-selectors)
3. [Taming Advanced CSS Selectors](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/taming-advanced-css-selectors/)

Comment: And I'll work through the code tonight